# Failure to secure a simple .war webapp with KeyCloak

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to secure a simple .war application on WildFly using KeyCloak.  I have run through the keycloak getting started tutorial and created a "demo" realm and successfully deployed to vanilla app with keycloak authentication.  I am trying to add KeyCloak to a sample WildFly webapp (https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/helloworld-rf)

I've added the webapp as a client in the keycloak admin console.

I have added security-constraint to the application web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>
            Entire Application
        </web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
</security-role>
```

And I have added the webapp to the keycloak adapter subsystem in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1">
    <secure-deployment name="helloworld-rf.war">
        <realm>demo</realm>
        <resource>helloworld-rf</resource>
        <public-client>true</public-client>
        <auth-server-url>http://localhost:8180/auth/</auth-server-url>
        <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
    </secure-deployment>
</subsystem>
```

My understanding from reading the documentation is that this should work but when I access the URL no keycloak auth comes up.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the name in the *web.xml* file must be the same of the resource's name in the *standalone.xml*. So for instance:

```
<web-resource-name>helloworld-rf</web-resource-name>
```

It should work now!